# Compute 3 New Date Fields

Tags: datetime

What is the best way to output 3 new dates relative to the first date? For instance, I have a date field called "medication_start" = 1/1/2010. I would like three new dates generated in 3 new fields in 6, 12, and 18 months from the start date.

Period 1 (6 months): 6/1/2010
Period 2 (12 months): 12/1/2010
Period 3 (18 months): 6/1/2011

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [views_php](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php) module. This module adds a field to the view and it also provides a few tokens. You can use the current row values. Note that you have to insert the main fields before the *PHP* field and exclude the *Price* field from display, Then the `$results,$data,$row` objects will give you the value of the row, Do the mathematical calculations and output the result.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like [Computed Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/computed_field) for this or you can write your own custom module. You could hook into node save using [hook_node_presave](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7) (since it acts on save and presave) and calculate the other 3 fields that you need to save. Either way should work pretty well. You would just use php date functions to calculate the new dates either way. There are a bunch of examples for computed field online and in their documentation you could use to draw inspiration from.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [math field](https://www.drupal.org/project/mathfield) too:

> The Math Field module defines a new field type to dynamically
>   calculate values on entity forms. This is an alternative to Computed
>   Field that does not require the use of PHP Filter.

this works much simpler than Computed field. enjoy